# How do 3rd-party programs modify the $PATH variable?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, catalina, zsh

When I echo my `$PATH` variable, I see the binaries of some programs that I have previously uninstalled, and conversely, I do not see the path to some of the binaries that I can use, such as `code`.

I am using the default `zsh` that comes pre-installed with macOS Catalina, and from my understanding, `$PATH` must be set in either one of its "main" start-up files in `/etc/` or a user configured override commonly found in the users home directory.

Yet, there has to be more because when I run:

```
cat /etc/zsh* ~/.zshrc /etc/profile /etc/bash* | grep PATH

## only ~/.zshrc is included because it's the only one in my home directory
```

The only result that is returned is the `PATH` variable I exported in my `~/.zshrc` file. This definition does not contain the uninstalled binaries that are still there when I echo `$PATH` or the "hidden" binaries that are not there when I echo `$PATH` but can still be executed anywhere from the command line.

So my questions are:

1. There must be some other file that I am not seeing that is updating the `$PATH` variable before my own user-configured file does. Where can this file be, if not the start-up files caught by my previous `cat` command?
2. I guess you don't have to update the `$PATH` variable with a binary's location to be able to run it anywhere in the terminal. If that is the case, how is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the content of `/etc/paths` and the files in `/etc/paths.d` which gets added to `PATH` by

```
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

in `/etc/profile` (or `/etc/zprofile`). Run `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s` to see what it does.